# Waiting Threads Resource Consumption

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, timer

**My Problem:**

Does large numbers of threads in JVM consume a lot of resources (memory, CPU), when the threads are `TIMED_WAIT` state (not sleeping) >99.9% of the time? When the threads are waiting, how much CPU overhead does it cost to maintain them if any are needed at all?

Does the answer also apply to non-JVM related environments (like linux kernels)?

**Context:**

My program receives a large number of space consuming packages. It store counts of similar attributes within the different packages.  After a given period of time after receiving a package(could be hours or days), that specific package expires and any count the package contributed to should be decremented.

Currently, I achieve these functionalities by storing all the packages in memory or disk. Every 5 minutes, I delete the expired packages from storage, and scan through the remaining packages to count the attributes. This method uses up a lot of memory, and has bad time complexity (`O(n)` for time and memory where n is the number of unexpired packages). This makes scalability of the program terrible.

One alternative way to approach this problem is to increment the attribute count every time a package comes by and start a `Timer()` thread that decrements the attribute count after the package expires. This eliminates the need to store all the bulky packages and cut the time complexity to `O(1)`. However, this creates another problem as my program will start having `O(n)` number of threads, which could cut into performance. Since most of the threads will be in the `TIMED_WAIT` state (Java’s `Timer()` invokes the `Object.wait(long)` method) the vast majority of their lifecycle, does it still impact the CPU in a very large way?

Comment: How many threads are you thinking might be waiting? A couple hundred or so might not be that taxing on the kernel for checking the thread's and when they need to be scheduled, but if you're queuing up 500+, you might want to re-consider your approach ..

Comment: I will probably have more than a couple hundred. Can you please explain why the kernel have to constantly check on the threads on `TIMED_WAIT`? I tried to find information on how the kernel does this specifically but can't find any desirable information.

Comment: ScheduledExecutor / a priority queue by timestamp of expiration with a single thread.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, a Java (or .NET) thread != a kernel/OS thread.

A Java [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is a high level wrapper that abstracts some of the functionality of a system thread; these kinds of threads are also known as managed threads. At the kernel level a thread only has 2 states, running and not running. There's some management information (stack, instruction pointers, thread id, etc.) that the kernel keeps track of, but there is no such thing at the kernel level as a thread that is in a [`TIMED_WAITING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) state (the .NET equivalent to the [`WaitSleepJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state). Those "states" only exists within those kinds of contexts (part of why the C++ [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) does not have a `state` member).

Having said that, when a managed thread is being blocked, it's being done so in a couple of ways (depending on how it is being requested to be blocked at the managed level); the implementations I've seen in the OpenJDK for the threading code utilize semaphores to handle the managed waits (which is what I've seen in other C++ frameworks that have a sort of "managed" thread class as well as in the .NET Core libraries), and utilize a mutex for other types of waits/locks.

Since most implementations will utilize some sort of locking mechanism (like a semaphore or mutex), the kernel generally does the same thing (at least where your question is concerned); that is, the kernel will take the thread off of the "run" queue and put it in the "wait" queue (a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)). Getting into thread scheduling and specifically how the kernel handles the execution of the threads is beyond the scope of this Q&A, especially since your question is in regards to Java and Java can be run on quite a few different types of OS (each of which handles threading completely differently).

Answering your questions more directly:

> Does large numbers of threads in JVM consume a lot of resources (memory, CPU), when the threads are TIMED_WAIT state (not sleeping) >99.9% of the time?

To this, there are a couple of things to note: the thread created consumes memory for the JVM (stack, ID, garbage collector, etc.) and the kernel consumes kernel memory to manage the thread at the kernel level. That memory that is consumed does not change unless you specifically say so. So if the thread is sleeping or running, the memory is the same.

The CPU is what will change based on the thread activity and the number of threads requested (remember, a thread also consumes kernel resources, thus has to be managed at a kernel level, so the more threads that have to be handled, the more kernel time must be consumed to manage them).

Keep in mind that the kernel times to schedule and run the threads are extremely minuscule (that's part of the point of the design), but it's still something to consider if you plan on running a **lot** of threads; additionally, if you know your application will be running on a CPU (or cluster) with only a few cores, the fewer cores you have available to you, the more the kernel has to context switch, adding additional time in general.

> When the threads are waiting, how much CPU overhead does it cost to maintain them if any are needed at all?

None. See above, but the CPU overhead used to manage the threads does not change based on the thread context. Extra CPU might be used for context switching and most certainly extra CPU will be utilized by the threads themselves when active, but there's no additional "cost" to the CPU to **maintain** a waiting thread vs. a running thread.

> Does the answer also apply to non-JVM related environments (like linux kernels)?

Yes and no. As stated, the managed contexts generally apply to most of those types of environments (e.g. Java, .NET, PHP, Lua, etc.), but those contexts can vary and the threading idioms and general functionality is dependant upon the kernel being utilized. So while one specific kernel might be able to handle 1000+ threads per process, some might have hard limits, others might have other issues with higher thread counts per process; you'll have to reference the OS/CPU specs to see what kind of limits you might have.

> Since most of the threads will be in the TIMED_WAIT state (Java’s Timer() invokes the Object.wait(long) method) the vast majority of their lifecycle, does it still impact the CPU in a very large way?

No (part of the point of a blocked thread), but something to consider: what if (edge case) all (or >50%) of those threads need to run at the exact same time? If you only have a few threads managing your packages, that might not be an issue, but say you have 500+; 250 threads all being woken at the same time would cause massive CPU contention.

Since you haven't posted any code, it's hard to make specific suggestions to your scenario, but one would be inclined to store a structure of attributes as a class and keep that class in a list or hash map that can be referenced in a `Timer` (or a separate thread) to see if the current time matches the expiration time of the package, then the "expire" code would run. This cuts down the number of threads to 1 and the access time to `O(1)`; but again, without code, that suggestion might not work in your scenario.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. As you state, there is no consumption difference running and runnable thread in kernal. But what if for "no thread" and runnable thread. What I mean is that, for many RPC framework, we have to specify a thread pool, and we always want to handle peak request so we specify a large value of min-size of thread pool, which creates lots of thread in TIME_WAITING state, does these threads cause significantly worse cpu consumption ?

Comment: @Jaskey In a threadpool situation, you will have additional CPU and memory for the pool to keep track of the threads and to handle the queue of actions as it passes that along to a running thread. And there will be additional CPU and memory for any additional threads created/destroyed, but for the individual threads themselves sitting in a `TIME_WAITING` state won't affect CPU any more than any other thread in the same state. In short, the underlying threads of the pool act like any other thread, but the thread pool itself is what will consume additional resources.

Comment: @txtechhelp thanks for you reply, but I still cant get the answer. For example, I create a thread pool of 200 threads(min size=200) for application A, after it handle 200 requests. and after that, 200 threads are in TIME_WAITING. comparing to another application Bwith only one thread in TIME_WAITING, does application A cost more cpu consumption than B does?

Comment: @Jaskey in short, no. App A won't use any more CPU than app B if, _and only if_, A and B are both in a `TIMED_WAITING` state. It should be noted though, that even with something like an AMD Ryzen with 128 cores, if app A has 200 threads in a threadpool, you have other issues to be mindful of, like what's the absolute need for 200 threadpool threads, but that's a different Q&A.

Comment: @txtechhelp So in a word, more threads with TIME_WAITING state will not cost more CPU, while more threads does cost more other resources , such as memory, is that right?

Comment: @Jaskey That's right! In a nutshell, you've got the idea. Explaining more and getting deeper gets into kernel design and requires more than can be put on this forum unfortunately. Very fortunately though there are tons of free resources on [kernel design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), [memory specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#References), [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_design) [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_architecture) and much more that can help tie it all together.