# C# waiting thread CPU consumption for a web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, cpu

I have a web service that I am trying to shorten single response time for a web request.
I have a lot of external service calls during lifetime of single request to my service and I found the solution by writing a simple graph library that
executes tasks on a graph which can be configurated outside to run parallel according to dependency between tasks.

[image: Something like that]

I am using TPL to run tasks on different threads and I have some concerns about my waiting 
(and will be continue execution when the graph executed) thread.

I read some great articles about how non blocking I/O works but I have some black points.
I know that it would be better if I dont have a main thread waiting during execution of request because for example if my thread pool has
100 thread and all of these threads in use at a point of time, that is a failure, my service cannot response to next request. That is not scalable.

I can increase thread pools thread number and I can accomplish that failure but as I read, having much more threads
can cause more memory usage (Every thread has its own stack, I am ok at that point that I have enough memory for example) 
and more CPU consumption (context switch?). That is what I dont understand at all.

I know that CPU does not spend idle time for threads that on waiting state. 
So I think my main thread will not consume CPU at this point?.

So my question is what is bad on my design ? If waiting threads does not consume CPU, 
what is wrong having a few more threads on waiting state about CPU?

It is something that kernel checks these threads on switch if its state changed to "ready to execute" ? If it is, is this really
a big deal I should take care of ? If it is not, could u please explain to me advantages of having less waiting threads for CPU ?

One of the most satisfied answer for me is here;
[Waiting Threads Resource Consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235700/waiting-threads-resource-consumption)
saying that:

> The CPU is what will change based on the thread activity and the
>   number of threads requested (remember, a thread also consumes kernel
>   resources, thus has to be managed at a kernel level, so the more
>   threads that have to be handled, the more kernel time must be consumed
>   to manage them).

But I also dont understand this part clearly. Could u please explain like I dont have much more knowledge how kernel or cpu handles threads.

Comment: Why do you have blocking IO calls? Can you not use `async` `await` in your codebase?

Comment: Of course I can, but having async I/O doesnt help me to increase my response time. That may help me to free more threads during I/O but actually I wanna understand benefits of not using waiting threads on CPU. My first concern is my main thread but you are right and you can also think like my calls are async and only waiting thread is my main thread

Comment: Threads during sleeping does not consume CPU in most (99% of OS) operating systems, so having lot of threads will consume only memory, but each time a thread is signaled (data ready I/O) kernel need to load it back (Stack, heap, memory..) and that consume CPU, so by creating threads you are trying to resolve a problem of queuing by letting your kernel doing it for you.

Comment: @rastbin I'm confused by what you mean increase your response time? A database call will take the exact same amount of time when it's blocking vs async. When the call is async, it uses no thread at all, which means while the db is processing, your app can respond with the least amount of threads needed. It also means you won't have threadpool starvation i.e. response times are through the roof but your CPU is sitting doing nothing. A blocking thread doesn't consume any resources really but your issue is a blocking thread is not doing any work.

Comment: @JohanP I mean shorten not increase, sorry for that. I am calling services parallel and shortening total response time, 
but what I wanna understand is what is the problem if I have more threadpool threads (not to cause threadpool starvation).
At this point I will have some waiting threads which waiting I/O, do these threads consume CPU ? If not, why should I use async I/O and trying to free up my threads.
(U can think like I have enough thread in my threadpool). My question is what is wrong to have I/O waiting threads if I have enough thread ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio so if you have enough thread in your pool, the only advantage of using async I/O (to free up threads) is shortening memory usage ?

Comment: @rastbin The thing is, how will you ever know if you have enough threads available? Over provisioning threads will cause memory usage spikes. What is going to happen if you get a sudden surge in traffic? Your site will fall over. Also, the threadpool will start to reduce the number of threads if it determines that threads are not getting used, i.e. at low traffic. You are just setting yourself up for a whole heap of hurt by blocking on IO and manually increasing threads. I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: @rastbin You can call multiple async IO concurrently using async await, you don't need to use `Parallel` or spin up new blocking threads.

Comment: @rastbin it depend on your operation system the implementation of thread, call back, async mybe they are all implemented in similar ways, but most of time async is implemented as a queue (for the same resource), so the advantage of using async is that you are not risking lot vs threads problems (race, deadlock, thread starvation, data corruption) + memory and cpu usage

Comment: You are focusing on a single issue, sure you can use more threads and wait on them. But with increase in threads, more time will be spent in context switching, so you will start to loose CPU cycles there. Also since your main thread is waiting, it can't service new clients. Which brings me to the number of request served. Basically having more number of threads is not good architecture as it does not scale well. Before using all your threads you need to be sure that you need all of them, if a lot of your threads are needed because you are waiting on them then it points to a wastage.

Comment: Also, with this architecture chances are your solution will probably end up being more complex as compared to an async approach.

Comment: `Also, with this architecture chances are your solution will probably end up being more complex as compared to an async approach` I'd say it's very unlikely. async/await has been introduced precisely because asynchronous code is inherently more complex than synchronous. There's really no reason for an async workflow to ever be simpler than a synchronous one

Comment: Personally I can think of two advantages brought by async for scalability. The most obvious one is decreased memory usage, though it matters less and less as RAM gets cheaper (unless you're in a containerized scenario). The other is thread management. You can manually create the threads but it's costly (hundreds of microseconds), or you can let the threadpool handle that for you. But the threadpool responds badly to traffic spikes, and you'll end-up in a starvation scenario where no thread is available to process your requests.

Comment: @peeyushsingh "increase in threads, more time will be spent in context switching, so you will start to loose CPU cycles there"
I think the answer is here but it is opposite to what I know. How do waiting threads cause spending more time on context switch ? I think waiting thread does not consume CPU till changing state to "ready to execute".
So why more sleeping thread cause context switch ? I think I need a little bit details.

Comment: @KevinGosse So u r saying that there is no impact on cpu but I can be end up with thread starvation, And if I have enough thread to process all request (setting min and max thread count for my thread pool) there is no problem with waiting threads and also blocking I/O on CPU performance?

Comment: @rastbin It's hard to tell which solution will use the most CPU, as they work very differently. But I doubt the difference is going to be big enough to be noticeable. That said, a golden rule in performance is that you cannot conclude anything before measuring.

Comment: @KevinGosse I was not comparing async to sync code. I was comparing the async approach to "having your own custom libraries doing similar thing by waiting/sleeping/joining on other threads". That is what appeared to me the users approach. Having worked on similar custom libraries, I think async/await is less complex as you are aware of the details. With custom libraries you have to discover the details all over again.

Comment: @rastbin, Sleeping threads would not consume cpu cycles but at some point of time the sleeping thread need to wake up and do their thing and that is when the hit would occur. I am assuming you will have more than one main thread (as it is a web service,which itself might be called multiple times). As KevinGosse mentioned, in the end best is to measure.